# How to set the People picker column to current user by leveraging JS/JQ (not spservices)

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

For one of the implementations, I am using a basic SharePoint list form to add entries in a list, there is a workflow attached to it as well. On NewForm.aspx, I have a column called 'Requester' (people picker field) which I would like to set to Current user when the form is opened. I have seen couple of solutions using SPServices for this type of question but I do not want to leverage SPServices, is there a different approach that someone took and works, if so please share the code.

FYI, I am working with SharePoint online. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this in SP2013 on-prem (online might be slightly different?):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadCurrentUser, 'clientpeoplepicker.js');
});

function loadCurrentUser() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        var currentUserRequest = $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/currentuser',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });
        currentUserRequest.done(function (result) {
            var peoplePickerCtrl = $('nobr:contains("Display Name of Field")').closest('tr').find('div.sp-peoplepicker-topLevel')
            var peoplePickerCtrlId = $(peoplePickerCtrl).attr('id');
            var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerCtrlId];
            var userObj = { 'Key': result.d.Email };
            peoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUser(userObj, true);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Works in SPOnline as well, thanks so much Dylan, appreciate the help.